# Why am I getting this error: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object

Tags: python, pickle

I was creating an infinitely looping problem (just for fun), but I encountered this error: "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object" following this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 2, in <module>
    exec(p.read())
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  [Previous line repeated 503 more times]
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object
```

I did not import the pickling module, and I don't know why this error is occurring.

I ran this code in the Python interpreter:

```
with open("Cool.py", "a")as p1:
    p1.write("""for _ in range(10):\n\t""")
    p1.write("""with open("Cool.py" "r")as p1:\n""")
    p1.write("""\t\tfor b in p1:\n""")
    p1.write("""\t\t\tprint(b)""")
```

I already have an empty .py file called "Cool.py" in my documents folder (I'm a Mac user).
After I run the above code, I run this code to call the file without having to open it:

```
with open("Cool.py") as p:
    exec(p.read())
```

I know it's lazy, but I'm mainly just curious why it came up with the pickle module.
Can anybody explain why I'm getting the error (and how to fix it--although that's less important).

Comment: If you're going to run the resultant `Cool.py` (but protip: keep your filenames lowercase because some OS are case sensitive) remember to also show what's _in_ that file. You show the code that generate it, and we can guess at what's in it, and we can run your code, but _you_ still need to show what's really in it when you run the code that's in your post (because you'll find it won't run ;). And then, if the problem only occurs when you exec it, the code that generates it becomes irrelevant: it is not relevant to the problem you're asking about anymore.

Comment: Not in the way the post claims it does. There is no recursion error, and so the post needs to be updated to include the code they _actually_ ran. It's only a small change, sure, but realizing you're not showing the code that reproduces the problem you're asking about, and editing your post accordingly, is part of writing a good question.

Answer (score 0):

With your first five lines of code, it opens the file `cool.py` and writes the following.(Please note that in the line `p1.write("""with open("Cool.py" "r")as p1:\n""")`, you have omitted the comma. It is supposed to be  `p1.write("""with open("Cool.py", "r")as p1:\n""")` Also I added `\n` in the last line to see what happens.

```
**#assume this is code_1**
for _ in range(10):
    with open("Cool.py", "r")as p1:
        for b in p1:
            print(b)
```

Now you are executing the following lines of code:

```
**#Assume this is code_2**
with open("Cool.py") as p:
    exec(p.read())
```

with the code `exec(p.read())` you are asking to execute the read code.
That is the code_1 will be executed as python code(See my comment to know what is code_1). Here you've asked to open the same file ten times. But, Here it's not over.

Everytime, the file is opened, the code_2 executes the code_1 in the file as it is `with open` (Hidden Meaning: if it is opened, then execute the code inside.) And each time it needs to open the same file 10 times, and each time when it is opened, the code is executed. It's a never ending process.

Though the purpose of `with open` is meant to avoid closing the file each time, this is how it behaves.

A better way to reduce the complication is: Write a code which writes a function in the file. Import it and run the function.

Comment: It guaranteed won't generate that.

Comment: I checked in terminal. The OP has written to print 10 times. But the same code was printed more than 20 times and then I got the error.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, If you run the code as it is, you may get different error(Maybe 'file not found'). As the OP has missed a comma between "Cool.py" and "r". I corrected and then ran.

Comment: Always include a description of what you had to change, if you change someone's code before running it. Because if _you_ need to change someone's code to get the result they claim they're getting, that is a change _they_ should (also) be making in their post.

Comment: ok. I'll do that